# Client controlled cache expiry times, using stale results

Tags: http, caching

How can I restrict the maximum age and/or staleness of a resource from the client?

## Scenario

I have 2 different pages, e.g. `/Show` and `/Edit`, both of these pages use ajax to query a list of items, eg `/Items`.

The `/Show` and `/Edit` have different constraints on how old (stale) the data is allowed to be, thus the server cannot clearly define the maximum age.

---

## Attempt 1

```
Request:
GET /Items
Cache-Control: max-age=5, max-stale=0

Response:
Cache-Control: private, max-stale=2592000, max-age=60
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 17:16:02 GMT

(wait 10 seconds)
GET /Items
Cache-Control: max-age=5, max-stale=0
```

### Expected Result

Second response would come from server.

### Actual Result

Response was served from cache.

---

## Attempt 2

```
Request:
GET /Items
Cache-Control: max-stale=60

Response:
Cache-Control: private, max-stale=2592000, max-age=5
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 17:16:02 GMT

(wait 10 seconds)
GET /Items
Cache-Control: max-stale=60
```

### Expected Result

Second response would come from cache

### Actual Result

Response was served from server.

---

I have also tried using other various combinations, and looked at min-fresh, none of which I have been able to get to work correctly.

Comment: Most HTTP stacks do not support features like max-stale. What client are you using?

Comment: I was getting that impression, various web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE). They also don't support max-age except when max-age=0

Comment: One potential problem is using max-stale with your response.  That's a header for clients only.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Comment: I thought it was applicable to both, since it's listed in the cache-request-directive as well as the cache-response-directive

Comment: Look again at that URL, @Chris.  It's not listed in cache-response-directive.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9 it is not appropriate to use `max-stale` in response. There is no explanation what it should mean for client cache. If you look only on `max-age` directive it works fine